# How many BTC transactions happened in 2019?

Tags: transactions, statistics

I'm interested in a comparison between different blockchains and payment networks.

Bitcoin has a block time of around 10 minutes, so there should be roughly 52,560 blocks in one year. However, the number of transactions per block varies.

Is the number of BTC transactions that happened in 2019 documented somewhere?

(Extra question: Is the volume in BTC or even USD at the time of the trade available?)

Comment: I've just found that it seems to be about 1.1 billion blockchain transactions in 2019 ([source](https://www.blocknative.com/blog/one-billion-transactions)). That is all blockchains, not only BTC.

Comment: Not sure what to do with your "extra question". What trade are you talking about? How is that related to the transaction count?

Answer (score 3):

There were 119,783,647 Bitcoin transactions confirmed in 2019. Note that many Bitcoin transactions perform [multiple payments](https://transactionfee.info/charts/payments-per-transaction/) at once.

Methodology:

1. Use the Blockchair block explorer to search for [Bitcoin transactions between the dates 2019-01-01 and 2019-12-31](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transactions?q=time(2019-01-01..2019-12-31)&s=id(asc)#) inclusive.
2. Read number of results for the query at the bottom of the result page in the "load more" link, add ten for the results presented on the first page:
   [image: "load more" link under search result]

The first block in 2019 was 556,459 and the last block was 610,690. So there were 2208.7 txs per block in average. I didn't check whether some blocks might have had funky timestamps that would have caused them to be incorrectly counted as out of the year.

Comment: I independently arrive at the exact same number.

Answer (score -1):

u can find all the statistics u want, or at least most of them, here
https://www.blockchain.com/charts/n-transactions-total
(I pointed to the exact curve, incase the asker share the same critic with the commenter

[image][image]
[image]
Total TXs in 2019= total in Jan1,2020- total in Dec31,2018
=~487.83*10⁶ - 368.981*10⁶
=~118.849m TXs

& There's also
https://m.btc.com/